# Reverse engineer assembly code to c code

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, x86-64, conditional-statements

I think this is actually a pretty simple problem.  I have to reverse engineer this assembly code to c code.  I'll also provide what I think is going on so you can hopefully point to where I went wrong and I can learn from my mistakes now.

```
.LFBO
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp,%rbp
    movl    %edi,-4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi,-8(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp),%eax
    compl   -8(%rbp),%eax
    jg      .L2
    movl    -8(%rbp),%eax
    jmp     .L3
.L2:
    movl    -4(%rbp),%eax
.L3:
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

So this is what I think is going on with this:
the first two lines after .LFBO:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp,%rbp
```

are just setting up the stack for the execution that is about to follow.

```
movl    %edi,-4(%rbp)
```

is grabbing the first variable, call it x

```
movl    %esi,-8(%rbp)
```

is grabbing the second variable call it y

```
movl    -4(%rbp),%eax
```

is grabbing x to be compared in the next line

```
compl   -8(%rbp),%eax
```

compares the variables x and y by computing x-y

```
jg      .L2
```

says jump to .L2 if x > y

if x <= y then compute the next lines without jumping to .L2

```
movl    -8(%rbp),%eax
```

copy x = y

```
jmp     .L3
```

jump to .L3

if x > y at the jg line then you jump to .L2: and complete this line

```
movl    -4(%rbp),%eax
```

this is where I realized I was really confused. It looks to me that you're copying x to x
then .L3 is completed and I think x is returned

Comment: Just to confirm, this is AT&T-syntax x86 assembly?

Comment: I don't think you were confused.  You are just looking at unoptimized code, so there are lines that are completely useless (like assigning x to x as you said).  So what do you think the function does, given all that?

Comment: Yes, I believe this is AT&T-syntax x86 assembly.  It was created from c code on a linux @Dai

Comment: So really what the code does is just take 2 variables (x and y) and then return the smaller of the two? @JS1

Comment: If I read the assembler code and your analysis correctly, it will return the bigger one: It jumps to `L2` if x is bigger, and it copies (needlessly) x into %rax at L2.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher yup. Sorry, that was a mistake.  It just returns the bigger one.

Comment: Your line where you say 'copying y to x' isn't -- its grabbing 'y' into a temp reg so it can be returned.  It's not doing anything with x, which is still sitting in the stack frame at "-4(%ebp)".  So the line where you're confused (x = x) isn't doing that either -- its grabbing 'x' into the same temp reg so it can be returned instead of the y value.

Comment: @ChrisDodd can you post as an answer so I can understand what you are saying better?

Comment: for reverse engineering problems it should be asked here http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't overthink it. Just gradually replace the assembly with C. Here is a possible sequence of transformations.

```
.LFBO
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp,%rbp
    movl    %edi,-4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi,-8(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp),%eax
    compl   -8(%rbp),%eax
    jg      .L2
    movl    -8(%rbp),%eax
    jmp     .L3
.L2:
    movl    -4(%rbp),%eax
.L3:
    popq    %rbp
    ret

----

int LFBO (int edi, int esi)
{
    rbp = rsp
    [rbp - 4] = edi
    [rbp - 8] = esi
    eax = [rbp - 4]
    if (eax > [rbp - 8]) goto L2
    eax = [rbp - 8]
    goto L3
L2:
    eax = [rbp - 4]
L3:
    return eax
}

----

int LFBO (int edi, int esi)
{
    int eax;

    eax = edi;
    if (eax > esi) goto L2;
    eax = esi;
    goto L3;
L2:
    eax = edi;
L3:
    return eax;
}

----    

int LFBO (int edi, int esi)
{
    int eax;

    eax = edi;
    if (eax <= esi) {
        eax = esi;
    }
    else {
        eax = edi;
    }
    return eax;
}

----

int LFBO (int edi, int esi)
{
    if (edi <= esi) {
        return esi;
    }
    else {
        return edi;
    }
}

----

int LFBO (int x, int y)
{
    if (x <= y) {
        return y;
    }
    else {
        return x;
    }
}

----

int LFBO (int x, int y)
{
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}
```

You can apply this strategy to any piece of assembly. Here I took the time to detail the various transformations. With practice you can get to the end result a lot quicker.

Answer (score 2):

```
LFB0(int x, int y){
    if (x<=y){
        x = y;
    }else{
        x = x;
    }
    return(x);
}
```

This is what I think we determined to be correct, with the help of the guys in the comments.

Comment: @thang isn't that the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
.LFBO
    pushq   %rbp                prolog
    movq    %rsp,%rbp           prolog
    movl    %edi,-4(%rbp)       [ebp-4] = edi
    movl    %esi,-8(%rbp)       [ebp-8] = esi
    movl    -4(%rbp),%eax       eax = [ebp-4] ie edi
    compl   -8(%rbp),%eax       cmp eax with [ebp-8] ie esi 
    jg      .L2                 ;jg requires <= 
    movl    -8(%rbp),%eax       so cutting the junk 
    jmp     .L3                 this effectively becomes
.L2:
    movl    -4(%rbp),%eax       ( edi <= esi ) ? { eax = esi } : { eax= edi} ; return;
.L3:
    popq    %rbp                epilog
    ret                         epilog
```

testing the hypothesis

```
lets compile the code in vc and test should compile unoptimized else 
clever compiler will cast away everything do 
/O1 push 10 pop eax retn;
/O2 mov eax ,10  ret

int main(void) {
int edi=8,esi=10;
if ( edi <= esi) { return esi; } else { return edi;}
}
```

disassembling the result

```
0:000> uf @eip
image00400000+0x1000:
00401000 55              push    ebp
00401001 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
00401003 83ec08          sub     esp,8
00401006 c745fc08000000  mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],8
0040100d c745f80a000000  mov     dword ptr [ebp-8],0Ah
00401014 8b45fc          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp-4]
00401017 3b45f8          cmp     eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]
0040101a 7f07            jg      image00400000+0x1023 (00401023)

image00400000+0x101c:
0040101c 8b45f8          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]
0040101f eb05            jmp     image00400000+0x1026 (00401026)

image00400000+0x1023:
00401023 8b45fc          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp-4]

image00400000+0x1026:
00401026 8be5            mov     esp,ebp
00401028 5d              pop     ebp
00401029 c3              ret
0:000>
```